# Menu based python program on Binary file handling using pickle module

Tags: binary, file-handling

```
import pickle
L=[]
def write():
    f=open("samp1.dat","ab")
    while True:
        n=input("enter name:")
        r=int(input("enter rollno:"))
        c=input("enter class:")
        tm=int(input("enter total marks:"))
        rec=[n,r,c,tm]
        L.append(rec)
        pickle.dump(L,f)
        print("record added:")   
        ch=input("do you want to add more records:")
        if ch in "Nn":
            break
    f.seek(0)
    f.close()               
def read():
    try:
        f=open("samp1.dat","rb")
        while True:
            x=pickle.load(f)
            print(x)
    except Exception:
        f.close()                
def search():
    f=open("samp1.dat","rb")
    #f.seek(0)
    rollno=int(input("enter rollno to search for record:"))
    try:
        x=pickle.load(f)
        for i in x:
            if i[1]==rollno:
                print("record found:",i)
                break
        else:
            print("Sorry no matching record found:")
    except Exception:
        f.close()     
def update():
    print("----------------------------------------")
    print("Updating records having total marks > 80:")
    found=False
    with open("samp1.dat","rb+")as f:
        x = list(pickle.load(f))
        for i in x:
            if i[3]>80:
                i[3]+=10
                found=True      
        f.seek(0)
        pickle.dump(x,f)
        if found==False:
            print("No match found:")
        else:
            f.seek(0)
            x=pickle.load(f)
            for i in x:
                print(i)
def delete():
    with open("samp1.dat","rb+") as f:
        x = list(pickle.load(f))
        n = int(input("Enter rollno:"))
        l1 = []
        for i in x:
            if i[1] == n:
                continue
            else:
                l1.append(i)
        f.seek(0)
        pickle.dump(l1, f)
while True:
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    print("1: To write")
    print("2: To Read")
    print("3: To search")
    print("4: To update")
    print("5: To delete")
    print("6: To quit")
    ch=int(input("Enter your choice:"))
    if ch==1:
        write()
    elif ch==2:
        read()
    elif ch==3:
        search()
    elif ch==4:
        update()
    elif ch==5:
        delete()
    elif ch==6:
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong choice, Enter choice between 1 to 6:")
```

The First time I executed the code all the functions worked well , when i tried to execute the same code again the write function does not append new records, it shows only the latest record, maybe it is overwriting records and the search, update and delete functions arent working properly..please suggest changes

```
type here
```